# Ruby: "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" in a for loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am trying to populate my database using a for loop and JSON parsing. When I do not attempt a for loop and just do it for a single object, it works. Here is my code:

```
         for i in 0..searchArray.size-1  #0..iTunesParsed['results'].size-1 // it is likely that searching for more than one item may not be benificial to us
                # NOTE: Need to make sure to only search for artists, filter only songs
                if !(ary.include? searchArray[i])
                    ary.push(searchArray[i])

                    # grabs artist name if not in database and adds it
                    # NOTE: this is occuring after the check for if elements are in the
                    # database, change it so this occurs first
                    if !(Artist.exists?(artist_name: ary[i]))

                          # replace all spaces with '+' so it may be passed to spotify
                            searchResult = searchArray[i]
                            if searchResult.match(/\s/)
                                searchResult.gsub!(/\s/,'+')
                            end

                            # grabbing the artist art from the Spotify api
                            # NOTE: have to fix 'special characters'
                            spotifyUrl = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + searchResult + "&type=artist"
                            spotifyUri = URI(spotifyUrl)
                            spotifyResponse = Net::HTTP.get(spotifyUri)
                        spotifyParsed =  JSON.parse(spotifyResponse)

                            # When putting item into the database, replace '+' with a space
                            searchResult.gsub!('+',' ')

                            # create database entry
                            artist = Artist.create(:artist_name =>
                                    searchResult, :artist_info=> nil,
                                            :biography => nil, :recent_albums => nil, :rating => nil,
                                                    :related_artists => nil, :artist_art => spotifyParsed['artists']['items'][0]['images'][0]['url'])

                    end
           end
```

The issue is mainly here:

```
artist_art => spotifyParsed['artists']['items'][0]['images'][0]['url'])
```

I have no idea what is happening. If anyone could guide me in the right direction, that would help a lot.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to access an element that does not exist. Try printing out your `spotifyParsed` just before you `# create database entry` and see its contents.

Comment: Hmm this is weird, when I try to parse it twice, the 'items' become empty. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Most likely Spotify's result does not contain 'items'. BTW, to make your code more "ruby-ish", you might consider using `.each { }` syntax instead of `for i in range`.

Comment: @QQPrinti please add whole stack trace in order to help us pinpoint where the error is.

Comment: you are probably accessing an invalid/non-existent index from the spotifyParsed array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there could be artists having no images. Use Rails’ [`try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) to handle these cases. Instead of:

```
:artist_art => spotifyParsed['artists']['items'][0]['images'][0]['url']
```

do:

```
:artist_art => spotifyParsed.try(:[],'artists')
                            .try(:[], 'items')
                            .try(:first)
                            .try(:[], 'images')
                            .try(:first)
                            .try(:[], 'url')
```

or use inline rescuer:

```
:artist_art => (spotifyParsed['artists']['items'][0]['images'][0]['url'] rescue nil)
```